# Use ember-intl along with ember-i18n

Tags: ember.js, internationalization, ember-addon, ember-i18n

I am using ember-i18n for translation. I installed ember-intl for formatting date in the application. Both addons have same helper {{t 'hello.world'}}. How could I use ember-i18n for translation and ember-intl for date formatting alone ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by explicitly defining what you want the `t` helper to do in your application. To do so, first generate a `t` helper using ember-cli:

```
ember g helper t
```

then, re-export the ember-i18n helper explicitly by pasting this code in the newly generated `app/helpers/t.js` file:

```
export { default } from 'ember-i18n/helper';
```

This is [exactly what ember-i18n is doing](https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n/blob/v5.0.1/app/helpers/t.js) to expose the `t` helper to your app.

[here is an ember-twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/b25a7bebfb27f0e951fc73425a22cab0?openFiles=helpers.t.js%2C) showing this working.